# Python3 Process.join() not actually waiting on Linux when the process is created in multi-thread

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, timeout

I need to put a **timeout on a process that is created inside a thread**, however i encountered a strange behavoir and i'm not sure how to proceed.

The following code executed **on Linux** produces a wierd bug where (if the *number of thrads is greater than 2* (my laptop has 8 core) or the code is *executed in a loop for a few times*) the **process.join() doesn't actually wait for the process to finish** or the timeout to expire but just goes on with the next instruction.

If the same code is executed **on Windows** with **python 3.9** it gives a **circular import error** in the libraries for no reason.

If it is executed with **python 3.8**  it **works almost perfectly** until like 256 threads, then gives the same stange beahvour on process.join() as in linux.

Error on windows Python 3.9:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Queue' from partially initialized module 'multiprocessing.queues' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Furthermore **if** i remove the return value from the process, so i **remove the Queue**. On **linux** the **process.join() start working properly** for arbitrarily large n_threads. However **running the code in a loop stiil gives the error** even for very small n_threads.

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from threading import Thread

def dummy_process():
    return random.randint(1, 10)

#function to retrieve process return value
def process_returner(queue, function, args):
    queue.put(function(*args))

#function that creates the process with timeout
def execute_with_timeout(function, args, timeout=3):
    
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(
        target=process_returner,
        args=(q, function, args),
        name="P",
    )
    p1.start()
    p1.join(timeout=timeout) # SOMETIME IT DOES NOT WAIT FOR THE PROCESS TO FINISH
    if p1.exitcode is None:
        print(f"Oops, {p1} timeouts!")# SO IT RAISES THIS ERROR even if nowhere near 3 secods have passed
        raise TimeoutError
    p1.terminate()
    return q.get() if not q.empty() else None


#thread that just call the new process and stores the return value in the given array
def dummy_thread(result_array, index):
    try:
        result_array[index] = execute_with_timeout(dummy_process, args=())
    except TimeoutError:
        pass


def test():
    #in loop because with low n_threads as 4 the error is not so common
    for _ in range(10):
        n_threads =8
        results = [-1] * n_threads
        threads = set()
        for i in range(n_threads):
            t = Thread(target=dummy_thread, args=(results, i))
            threads.add(t)
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
        print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with [this warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) in the documentation: "Note that the start(), join(), is_alive(), terminate() and exitcode methods should only be called by the process that created the process object."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I am indeed creating the new process, calling the .start() and calling the .join() from the same process, literally on 3 consecutive lines. So I don't think that I violated that warning or using the library improperly

Comment: Attempting to join, and then terminate the process on failure, while it has enqueued items, can lead to deadlocks and the queue becoming corrupted. While it shouldn't skip the timeout itself (like you describe it), it should be worth fixing that and seeing if the error persists. Useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084802/16310741

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when using the `multiprocessing` module on Linux. `Process.join()` started returning immediately instead of waiting. `exitcode` would be equal to `None` and `is_alive()` would return `True`.

It turns out the problem wasn't in the Python code. I was calling my Python program from a Bash script that would sometimes execute `trap "" SIGCHLD`. Normally, setting `trap` only affects the script itself, but `trap "" some_signal` tells the shell's child processes to ignore the signal as well. Blocking `SIGCHLD` interferes with the `multiprocessing` module.

In my case, adding `signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_DFL)` to the beginning of the Python program fixed the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).