# Multiprocess.Process not exiting while target function returns

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I spawn a subprocess which simply copy data from one queue to another. The problem is: after subprocess`s target function return, the subprocess seems not exsiting as expect. It hangs on the pdet.join() line.

What's causing it to hang?

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def load( qdet):
    i = 0
    while i < 500:
        im = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), 'uint8')
        i += 1
        print(i)
        qdet.put(im)

    print('load exit.')


def detect(qdet, qshw):
    while True:
        im = qdet.get()
        if im is None:
            break

        qshw.put(im)

    print('detect exit.')


def main():
    qdet = mp.Queue()
    qshw = mp.Queue()

    load(qdet)

    pdet = mp.Process(target=detect, args=(qdet, qshw,))
    pdet.start()

    qdet.put(None)
    pdet.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    main()
```

Comment: Take a look at the [multiprocessing programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines), subitem _Joining processes that use queues_.

Comment: So, do you really need to `.join()`?

Comment: Where is the subprocess when it's hanging? What was the last thing that happened there?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the if a process puts items on a queue, it will not exit until the items are flushed from the other end. From the documentation:

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait
> before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
> “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call
> the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this
> behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that
> all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed
> before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that
> processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember
> also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

You should therefore make sure that all items from the queue have been removed before attempting to join. However, you can also workaround this by using manager queues, which introduce some overhead but are not affected by such issues:

```
def main():
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        qdet = manager.Queue()
        qshw = manager.Queue()

        load(qdet)

        pdet = mp.Process(target=detect, args=(qdet, qshw,))
        pdet.start()

        qdet.put(None)
        pdet.join()
```

Comment: Concise and comprehensive. Thanks