# Python multiprocessing Queue + Process hanging

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use `multiprocessing.Queue` to manage some tasks that are sent by the main process and picked up by "worker" processes (`multiprocessing.Process`). The workers then run the task and put the results into a result queue.

Here is my main script:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, freeze_support
import auxiliaries as aux
import functions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    
    start = time.perf_counter()
    # number of processess
    nprocs = 3

    # define the tasks
    tasks = [(functions.get_stats_from_uniform_dist, (2**23, i)) for i in range(600)]

    # start the queues
    task_queue = Queue()
    result_queue = Queue()

    # populate task queue
    for task in tasks:
        task_queue.put(task)

    # after all tasks are in the queue, send a message to stop picking...
    for _ in range(nprocs):
        task_queue.put('STOP')

    # start workers 
    procs = []
    for _ in range(nprocs):
        p = Process(target=aux.worker, args=(task_queue, result_queue))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    # print what's in the result queue
    while not result_queue.empty():
        print(result_queue.get())
```

The imported modules are

**auxiliaries.py**

```py
from multiprocessing import current_process

def calculate(func, args):
    """
    Calculates a certain function for a list of arguments. Returns a string with the result.

    Arguments:
        - func (string): function name
        - args (list): list of arguments
    """
    result = func(*args)
    string = current_process().name
    string = string + " says " + func.__name__ + str(args)
    string = string + " = " + str(result)
    return string


def worker(inputQueue, outputQueue):
    """
    Picks up work from the inputQueue and outputs result to outputQueue.

    Inputs:
        - inputQueue (multiprocessing.Queue)
        - outputQueue (multiprocessing.Queue)
    """
    for func, args in iter(inputQueue.get, 'STOP'):
        result = calculate(func, args)
        outputQueue.put(result)
```

and
**functions.py**

```py
import numpy as np

def get_stats_from_uniform_dist(nDraws, seed):
    """
    Calculates average and standard deviation of nDraws from NumPy's random.rand().

    Arguments:
        - nDraws (int): number of elements to draw
        - seed (int): random number generator's seed

    Returns:
        - results (list): [average, std]
    """
    np.random.seed(seed)
    x = np.random.rand(nDraws)
    return [x.mean(), x.std()]
```

This is entirely based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-examples

Everything runs okay with up to ~500 tasks. After that, the code hangs. It's looking like one of the processes never finishes so it gets stuck when I join them.
It does not look like the queues are getting full. I suspect that one of the processes is not finding the "STOP" entry in the `task_queue`, so it keeps trying to `.get()` forever, but I can't understand how and why that would happen. Any ideas on what could be causing the lock? Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to join the processes before removing everything from `result_queue`? If that is the case, then it is documented that the process will hang. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084802/16310741

Comment: Interesting... thanks for pointing me to that. It is indeed documented (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines). This becomes a problem then. How can I make sure to empty the queue if I can't know when the processes are done putting stuff there by joining them?

Comment: Have you thought about using a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` instead of a `multiprocessing.Queue`?  In that case you could replace the loop around p.join with a single call to `queue.join`.  You would also have to modify the worker to call `queue.task_done.`  But this looks like a cleaner solution.

Comment: I tried to use a `JoinableQueue`, but it seems to still hang... It may require some additional changes, but I'm moving on for now

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have a better time just using the higher-level `Pool.imap_unordered()` method, which does all of that for you.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_stats_from_uniform_dist(task):
    nDraws, seed = task
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(nprocs) as p:
        tasks = [(2**23, i) for i in range(600)]
        results = list(p.imap_unordered(functions.get_stats_from_uniform_dist, tasks, chunksize=10))
```

Comment: That does work with a much larger number of tasks than 500, thanks! However, this script is just the stepping stone to a broader project where using a Queue would be preferable, so I want to understand what is not working with `Queue` + `Process`...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    .
    .
    .

    # start workers 
    procs = []
    for _ in range(nprocs):
        p = Process(target=aux.worker, args=(task_queue, result_queue))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    # print what's in the result queue
    while not result_queue.empty():
        print(result_queue.get())
```

or, more specifically, the fact that I am joining the processes before the `result_queue` is drained.
As @Charchit pointed out, this is actually mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines):

> Joining processes that use queues
>
> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

The solution I'm using is, at the expense of spawning yet another process, employing a `Manager.Queue()` instead, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73078478/multiprocess-process-not-exiting-while-target-function-returns/73084802#73084802). The main script is then

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support, Manager
import auxiliaries as aux
import functions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    
    # number of processess
    nprocs = 3

    # define the tasks
    tasks = [(functions.get_stats_from_uniform_dist, (2**18, i)) for i in range(1000)]

    # use a manager context to share queues between processes
    manager = Manager()
    task_queue = manager.Queue()
    result_queue = manager.Queue()

    # populate task queue
    for task in tasks:
        task_queue.put(task)

    # after all tasks are in the queue, send a message to stop picking...
    for _ in range(nprocs):
        task_queue.put('STOP')

    # start processes (workers)
    procs = []
    for _ in range(nprocs):
        p = Process(target=aux.worker, args=(task_queue, result_queue))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    # wait until workers are done
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    # print what's in the result queue
    while not result_queue.empty():
        print(result_queue.get())
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can use sentinel items too. Decide on an object that your workers will never put on a queue normally, such as a string with value `"~End"`. This will be the sentinel item your workers should put on the queue when they have completed their work. Then when you are retrieving items from the queue, include a check to see whether the item is a sentinel. If it is, increment a counter. When the counter equals the number of workers you started, you can then safely join the processes.

Comment: I tried the sentinel method... even though the queue is empty and the counter adds up to the number of workers, it still hangs when I join the processes :/

Comment: Hard to say without examples, might just be an issue with how you are implementing it. I also want to add that `result_queue.empty()` is not very reliable.

Comment: Right, I understand it's hard to tell without an example. I tried in several different ways, but since nothing changed I needed to move on. The manager queue is working. And yes, I noticed that the `.empty()` is not reliable. I moved to post a "DONE" message to the `result_queue` after joining the processes, then using that as a sentinel. Thanks, @Charchit, your comments were quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try queue.get before task.join.  The issue is likely the queue is getting full and the producer task (sub processes) waiting ever for put-ing into the queue.  The suggested change will avoid the deadlock situation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).