# python multiprocessing doesn't work(doesn't go back to parent process) using Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a question about Queue in python multiprocessing.

I tried to perform multiprocessing operation on DataFrame using Queue and Process.

However, only sub-processes are executed, and subsequent operations are not executed.

In other words, only the completion messages of sub-processes are printed, and subsequent operations are not executed.

The code I ran is below.

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import os
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
import time

count_of_core = 8

def add_rownum_col(queue, df_of_split) :

    sub_process_id = os.getpid()
    print("!!! {} subprocess started !!!".format(sub_process_id), "\n")
    df_of_split_with_rownum_col = sqldf("SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS ROWNUM_ FROM df_of_split")
    print("* making df_of_split_with_rownum_col finished", "\n")
    print(df_of_split_with_rownum_col, "\n")
    queue.put(df_of_split_with_rownum_col)
    print("!!! {} subprocess finished !!!".format(sub_process_id), "\n")

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parent_process_id = os.getpid()
    print("* parent_process_id :", parent_process_id, "\n")

    df_of_example = pd.read_csv('../data/example_for_multiprocessing.csv', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
    print("* df_of_example :", "\n")
    print(df_of_example, "\n")
    print("* length of df_of_example :", len(df_of_example), "\n")

    df_of_split   = np.array_split(df_of_example, count_of_core)
    print("count of batch :", len(df_of_split), "\n")

    print("!!! multiprocessing started !!!", "\n")
    
    df_of_result = pd.DataFrame()
    queue = Queue()
    start_time_of_multiprocessing = time.time()

    p_0 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[0]))
    p_0.start()

    p_1 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[1]))
    p_1.start()

    p_2 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[2]))
    p_2.start()
    
    p_3 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[3]))
    p_3.start()

    p_4 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[4]))
    p_4.start()

    p_5 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[5]))
    p_5.start()

    p_6 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[6]))
    p_6.start()

    p_7 = Process(target = add_rownum_col, args = (queue, df_of_split[7]))
    p_7.start()

    p_0.join()
    p_1.join()
    p_2.join()
    p_3.join()
    p_4.join()
    p_5.join()
    p_6.join()
    p_7.join()

    print("!!! multiprocessing finished !!!")
    print("!!! back to parent process({}) !!!".format(parent_process_id))
    print("* time for multiprocessing :", time.time() - start_time_of_multiprocessing, "\n")

    print("!!! concatenating all batches in queue started !!!", "\n")
    queue.put('exit')
    while True :

        df_batch = queue.get()
        if df_batch == 'exit':
            break
        else:
            df_of_result = pd.concat([df_of_result, df_batch])

    print("!!! concatenating all batches in queue finished !!!", "\n")

    print("* df_of_result :", "\n")
    print(df_of_result, "\n")
    print("* length of df_of_result :", len(df_of_result), "\n")
```

It seems that it cannot return to the parent-process after the operation of sub-processes is finished.

I would like to get a detailed answer as to why this problem occurred.

Please provide detailed answer.

(I'm using python 3.7)

Comment: What happens if you have 100 processes? Would you write 3 lines of code for each? Use a list instead. Also please post the output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084802/16310741