# python subprocess does not terminate although inner method exits

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to debug a python3 script and I'm stuck. It contains subprocesses (`multiprocessing.Process`) that execute async stuff.
This has approximately the following structure:

```py
def start_service():
    asyncio.run(start_service_async())
    print("Exiting start_service")

async def start_service_async():
    ...   # a lot a stuff happens here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_service)
    proc.start()
    print("Process started")
    proc.join()
    print("Process terminated")
```

My problem is that the process does not terminate properly:

- I see the message "Exiting start_service"
- I do NOT see "Process terminated"

This means that the process does not terminate, because `proc.join()` does not exit. But on the other hand the method `start_service` exits, since it prints "Exiting start_service".

I have an understanding problem: how is this possible?

In order to find my bug, what are the kind of things that could prevent the process to terminate, although the inner method does exit?

thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: are you using a multiprocessing.Queue inside the process?

Comment: Yes I'm using several `multiprocessing.Queue`, that are created in the main process and passed as argument in the call `Process(target=... `, as well as a `multiprocessing.Event()`

Comment: then this seems it will be relevant to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084802/16310741