# Python Multiprocessing queue.get() timeout when queue is not empty

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am attempting to implement a multiprocessing queue which is filled from the second process function. Testing this function, it appears the multiprocess is working correctly, and the queue appears to be filling. I have confirmed the data in the worker function is correct by printing out the data. Furthermore, I have confirmed that the qsize increases afte running `queue.put(ret)`. However, running `queue.get()` results in the code hanging and timing out. It seems this is somehow related to the data I am putting into the queue, since a simple `queue.put("hello")` in my worker function works correctly. Any ideas why this would be happening? I have attached the relevant code below.

```
def worker(queue):
    print("Running worker")
    ret = odrive.find_any()
    queue.put(ret)
    #print(ret)

def findODrives():
    M = []
    foundAll = False
    queue = Queue()
    print("Starting findODrives")
    while foundAll == False:
        doneFinding = False
        while doneFinding == False:
            print("Finding ODrive")
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, name="ODriveFind", args=(queue,))
            p.start()
            p.join(10)
            if p.is_alive():
                print("worker is running... let's kill it...")
                # Terminate worker
                p.terminate()
                p.join()
                doneFinding = True
            elif(queue.qsize() != 0):
                print("Queue is not zero")
                print((queue.qsize()))
                try:
                    obj = queue.get(timeout=10)
                except:
                    print("Failed to get data in queue")
                print(obj)
                M.append(obj)
                print("test")
                print("Found ODrive with serial number: " + str(M[-1].serial_number))

def main():
    while(True):
        inp = input("Please press enter to continue with an operation, or QUIT to exit...")
        if inp == "QUIT":
            exit()
        MList = findODrives()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit:
Forgot to include import statements. I am using the multiprocessing queue, as shown:

```
import odrive
from odrive.enums import *
from odrive.utils import *
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using a queue that's appropriate for multiprocessing? We can't be sure as you've missed out some very important code in your question

Comment: I *strongly* recommend replacing `except:` with `except queue.Empty:` (adding `import queue` to the top of your file). As written, *any* exception will be caught, treated as a timeout, and all details discarded. If you typo a name, if someone hits Ctrl-C, if you run out of memory, etc., they'll all be treated the same. Catch the exceptions you expect, and no others. *Never* use bare `except:` unless you ultimately reraise the exception (with a bare `raise`) after performing whatever logging and cleanup (e.g. rolling back a failed DB transaction) you need to do.

Comment: @Vlad: Good catch; if they did `from queue import Queue` that won't work, where `from multiprocessing import Queue` would. We need a [MCVE] to catch stuff like that.

Comment: I am using the multiprocessing queue, see edit to post

Comment: Killing a process that is putting items on a queue is more than likely to not end well, and may as well be the problem here

Comment: I am only killing the process if the process times out, which means I am not doing anything with the information in the queue and I am exiting the loop

Comment: @Nathan What you said is *theoretically* correct.  However, the problem is that your process will always time out because a process which has put items on a queue will deadlock if an attempt to join it is made. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084802/16310741

Answer (score 1):

use this for queue

```
import multiprocessing

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
queue = manager.Queue()
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but unfortunately this results in a new error: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'fibre.libfibre.anonymous_interface_1951672175600'>: attribute lookup anonymous_interface_1951672175600 on fibre.libfibre failed`

Comment: First problem is you should start multiprocessing.Process() inside if __name__ = "__main__":

Comment: and second is use while loop in  worker to keep it running

Comment: i think then you get no error

Comment: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'fibre.libfibre.anonymous_interface_1951672175600'>: attribute lookup anonymous_interface_1951672175600 on fibre.libfibre failed this is not related to multiprocessing or queue it is because of this  ret = odrive.find_any()

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the question but demonstrates how a queue can be used for communication between sub-processes. In this case a sort of client/server strategy.

What's really important is that you have to have some way of telling the server that it's not going to receive any more data so that it can terminate gracefully. So, what we do here is send some integers to the queue. When we've finished we send None. Anything the server receives that is not None is printed. If None is received it terminates.

Hopefully this will help you to build on good practice:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager

def server(q):
    while (v := q.get()) is not None:
        print(v)

def client(q):
    for i in range(10):
        q.put(i)
    q.put(None)

def process():
    with Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            wait(executor.submit(func, q) for func in (server, client))
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process()
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```